# Como utilizar várias classes como User no Identity - Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Quero usar 2 classes como User no Identity e não consegui visualizar essa alteração no código.

Vamos supor que irei utilizar a classe padrão "ApplicationUser" que gera uma tabela "AspNetUsers" e quero usar uma outra tabela "Clientes" que herda de Identity.

A classe ApplicationUser já herda de Identity e funciona direitinho. Vi que existe uma classe ApplicationUserManager e outras que herdam de ApplicationUser. Exemplo:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>

public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>


public class Cliente: IdentityUser
```

A minha dúvida é se vou precisar criar novas classes para herdar de Cliente, exemplo:

```
public class ApplicationUserManagerCliente : UserManager<Cliente>
public class ApplicationSignInManagerCliente : SignInManager<Cliente, string>
```

Seria isso ou estou pensando errado?

Comment: Qual o motivo de você ter que usar 2 classes? Não seria melhor usar apenas `Cliente`?

Comment: É porque quero usar uma classe de usuário para o acesso da área administrativa do site. e uma outra classe de usuário para o acesso externo. Entendeu?

Comment: @GabrielMoura isso é autorização, não faz sentido 2 usuários, crie 1 e de autorização para a determinada área que ele poderá ou não acessar

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer criar dois tipos de usuários o Usuário Convencional (UserEntity) e o
Administrador do Sistema (AdminUserEntity). O UserEntity vai acessar o site normal e o Administrador irá acessar outro site(adm).

Acredido que o ideal seria, criar um único usuário com as características padrão entre os 2 e dê a eles Claims especializadas, por ex Perfil = Admin, AcessoSites = OutroSite.

Veja se esse link aqui pode te ajudar:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855428/how-to-change-table-names-for-asp-net-identity-2-0-with-int-id-columns

tem um tutorial que pode lhe ajudar : http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/08/asp-net-identity-tutorial-completo/